# Error trying to create a database in mssql

Tags: sql-server

While creating SQL database its throws error of -

> A SQL editor must have focus before executing this command.

Comment: In what context? Are you using SSMS? What version? This question is unclear as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a connection to the server. Connect and then try again.